# Cross-compiling static QEMU for Windows

Tags: makefile, debian, mingw, configure, qemu

I've been trying to compile a static QEMU executable for Windows on a Debian box, and ran into some problems. (I'm using [this guide](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/wiki/How_to_build_QEMU#Windows_cross_build_on_Debian) as a reference.)

When I compile without the static flag everything works but when I compile using the static flag I get the following error during the call to `configure`:

```
ERROR: zlib check failed
       Make sure to have the zlib libs and headers installed.
```

This is the command line:

```
WORK=/media/Work/qemu
cd $WORK/build/w32
(export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$WORK/install/w32/lib/pkgconfig ; 
export PKG_CONFIG_PREFIX=$WORK/install/w32 ;
#export BASH_X=-x ;
bash $BASH_X ../../qemu.git/configure --target-list="i386-softmmu" \
--cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- \
--extra-ldflags="-L$WORK/install/w32/lib" \
--extra-cflags="-I$WORK/install/w32/include" \
--static \
)
```

Comment: What is the command you are sending to the compiler?

Comment: See my edit - this happens during the call to configure, I added the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the zlib test using the command line input

```
./configure --disable-zlib-test
```

Zlib will be needed to build qemu, but it will not test for the library during configure. If the library is available in the proper location during build process, you can try the above command to proceed.